# Pass list of ids between forms

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET c# project.

I have to pass a list of values (id numbers such as "23,4455,21,2,765,...) from one form to another. Since QueryString is not possible because the list could be long, which is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks for all your answers, you are helping a lot !!!
I decided to do this:

On the first form:

List lRecipients = new List();
.....
Session["Recipients"] = lRecipients;

On the final form:
List lRecipients = (List)Session["Recipients"];
Session.Remove("Recipients");

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Session` collection.

In the first page, use:

```
List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();
...
Session["someKey"] = listOfInts
```

And in the second page, retrieve it like this:

```
List<int> listOfInts = Session["someKey"] as List<int>;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using asp.net webforms you can put it into a session variable to pass stuff from page to page.  You've got to be concise of the potential performance issues of putting lots of stuff into session mind.

```
Session["ListOfStff"] = "15,25,44.etc";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of ways to pass this data. Which you choose will depend on your environment.

Session state is useful, but is constrained by the number of concurrent users on the system and the amount of available memory on the server. Consider this when deciding whether or not to use Session state. If you do choose session state for this operation, be sure to remove the data when you're done processing the request.

You could use a hidden input field, with runat="server" applied to it. This will make its data available server-side, and it will only last for the duration of the request. The pros of this technique are that it's accessible to both the server code and the client-side JavaScript. However, it also means that the size of your request is increased, and it may take more work to get the data where you want it (and back out).

Depending on how much data's involved, you could implement a web service to serialize the data to a temporary storage medium (say, a database table), and get back a "request handle." Then, you could pass the request handle on the query string to the next form and it could use the "handle" to fetch the data from your medium.

There are all kinds of different ways to deal with this scenario, but the best choice will depend on your environment, time to develop, and costs.

Answer (score 0):

For Asp.NET MVC you can use ViewData.

ViewData["ID"] = "";